# SCORM reporting to LMS

Tags: scorm

I'll prefix this with: I don't much about SCORM.

I'm the maintainer for a training video delivery platform. It shows videos but doesn't test users. Clients of the company can download SCORM modules (that is a zip) which contains a link to the video on our server.

Some clients are now asking for reporting so that they know their LMS users finish watching a video. At the moment, they just know if the user loads the module but nothing else.

As for working out if the current user has watched the film, I can do that. It's just a bit of javascript to interact with the video player. Fine.

But how do I communicate that event back to the LMS? Do I post it to their server? How do I know where it is? What if it's behind a firewall? Do they poll my server? In both cases how do I identify a user from the LMS in a way that when the results go back, they line up in the LMS?

What is the standard way of a learning management system finding out the completion status of an external module like ours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SCORM API is what you're looking for.  It enables active communication of completion status (among many other things) between the SCO (your module) and the LMS.

At runtime, a discovery algorithm (written in JS) is used to locate the API handle, which is just a JS Object.  You, as the content developer, work with that API handle, and *it* does all the client-server communication, so you don't have to.  :-)

You can find a technical overview of how to locate and use the SCORM API [here](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/).

I'm more of the "learn by example" type, so I'd also recommend downloading one of Rustici's golf (*pause*) courses.  Check out their [Basic Run-Time Calls Course](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/#basicruntime) to see how they are accessing and interacting with the SCORM API.  They'll be doing exactly what you're looking to do.

The official SCORM docs can be found on [adlnet.gov](http://www.adlnet.gov/Pages/Default.aspx), and they have an entire book dedicated to the RTE, but I doubt you'll need to dive that deep.

Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you for your answer, SCORM-RTE *is* what I was looking for and those examples are really useful.